# Combining two euclidean distance rasters in Raster Calculator

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3

I have two euclidean disance rasters and would like to combine them for use in a multi criteria evaluation. Could anyone advise me on the syntax to use within Raster Calculator (ArcGIS 10.3.1)? There are not any areas of NoData.

Answer (score 1):

for a multicriteria evaluation, you first need to recode your two rasters in the same interval where the maxima have the same meaning (e.g. 0 for worse and 10 for best). Linear or log transforms are the most widely used.

Then you need to combine the two layer in a weighted sum, with all weight positive and summing at 1.

Those two step are quite straightforward in map algebra, just use the name of your layer within **" "**. e.g.

```
"dist1.tif"*0.4 + "dist2.tif"*0.6
```